# Image resizing Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, resize, image-manipulation

I have horizontal set of 4 images. The resize function works on mouseover event. This means that if I move the mouse very fast or slow over these images they will All resize. Because of this I need the user to  keep the mouse over for at least 1.5 sec over a given image and then proceed with the resize. This is the unproper code:

```
$('a img').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).delay(1500).animate({
                width: "315px",
                height: "225px",
                marginLeft: "-50px"
            }, 1500 );
        });
        $('a img').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: "210px",
            height: "150px",
            marginTop: "0px",
            marginLeft: "0px"
        }, 500 );
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `.setTimeout()`

```
$('a img').mouseover(function(){
        var imgElement = $(this);
        var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(
        function(){ 
            imgElement.animate({
                width: "315px",
                height: "225px",
                marginLeft: "-50px"
            }, 1500 );
         }, 1500);
         imgElement.data("timeout", timeoutID);
    });
    $('a img').mouseout(function(){
        var imgElement = $(this);
        var timeoutID = imgElement.data("timeout");
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        $(this).animate({
            width: "210px",
            height: "150px",
            marginTop: "0px",
            marginLeft: "0px"
        }, 500 );
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use setTimeout and clearTimeout for this:

also [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is a shortcut method in jQuery to handle mouseOver and mouseOut at the same time.

```
var TimeoutHandler = 0;
var ImageToAnimate = null;

function AnimationIn()
{
    // animate ImageToAnimate 
}

function AnimationOut(image)
{
    // animate image
}

$('a img').hover(function()
{
     clearTimeout(TimeoutHandler );
     ImageToAnimate = this;
     TimeoutHandler = setTimeout(AnimationIn, 1500);
}, function()
{
     AnimationOut(this);
});
```

Comment: Technically, `hover()` combines `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`, and **not** `mouseover()` and `mouseout()`.  But yes, `hover()` [is totally the way to go](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).  +1

Comment: I don't see you clearing the timer when the mouse leaves before the animation has fired.

Comment: it's not when mouse leaves, it's when it enters, the reason is if you go over 10 images very fast each one will clear the timer previous one started so always the last will start after 1.5 second.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact logic you want, but here's one way to do it.  I didn't hook up the actual animation, but rather just show you when it would trigger.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/227688911_f5X9o-Ti.jpg" border="0">
<img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/231469043_zkRUp-Ti.jpg" border="0">
<img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/227688911_f5X9o-Ti.jpg" border="0">
<img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/231469043_zkRUp-Ti.jpg" border="0">
<img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/227688911_f5X9o-Ti.jpg" border="0">
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {

    var myTimer = null;

    function animate() {
        $("#result").append("go, ");
    }

    $(".container").mouseenter(function() {
        if (!myTimer) {
            myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                myTimer = null;
                animate();
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
    $(".container").mouseleave(function(){
        if (myTimer) {
            clearTimeout(myTimer);
            myTimer = null;
        }
    });
}());
```

This could be made a tiny bit more foolproof by checking if the mouse was still over the iamges before firing the animation just in case the mouseleave event was missed somehow.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9q36R/