# Javascript: display window on mouseover time interval of 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, setinterval, onmouseover

I am trying to have a window display when the mouse is hovered over an image for 2 seconds or more, of course if the user does not hover for at least 2 seconds I do not want the window to be displayed.

Below is a snippet of the code that I used. As the code is now the window shows up at two seconds regardless of how long the user hovered over the image. I am trying to get something similar to the delayed hover effect in Netflix. I am sure I am going about it all wrong. So thanks in advance for your help.

```
<img name="img4" onMouseOver="WindowDelay(this);" onmouseout="closeDetails();" 
        src="images/MyImage.jpg" height="240" width="166"/>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
       var countTime = 0;
       var windowTimer = null

       function WindowDelay(thatImg)
       {
            windowTimer = window.setInterval(function() {countT(thatImg);}, 1000);
       }   

       function countT(thatImg)
       {
            countTime++;

            if (countTime == 2)
            {
                openDetails(thatImg);
                clearInterval(windowTimer);
                countTime = 0;
            }

        }
</script>
```

Comment: Pretty similar question/answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701056/image-resizing-jquery

Comment: I have not heard of jquery. I guess I have not gotten that far in my book yet. I will check it out. Thanks

Comment: jQuery is a free, open source javascript library that makes lots of web programming faster and easier across many browsers: http://jquery.com/.  It is extremely popular.  By some counts, it's used by ~35% of the sites on the web which is nearly 80% of the sites using a recognizable library.

Comment: Looks like I will be going to the library again. :) Thanks for your helpful information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the mouse goes over the element, use `setTimeout` to open the window in two seconds. If the user mouses off of the element, use `clearTimeout` to stop the future window opening.